# Views mysteriously disappearing from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my android application every screen extends a **Fragment** and I am using a MVC architecture to navigate between them.

I have 2 fragments giving me problems after implementing Drag and Drop. My Fragment consists of a ListView, and another smaller View that sits on top. I have made it so if you click on the smaller list view you can drag up and down the Y-axis. If it is dragged passed a certain point it will transition to the other screen/fragment via the **Controller** class. If you release and it is not over the "transition threshold" then it will return to its original state.

**The Problem**

I can drag it up and down over and over and it continues to reset perfectly to its original position, and then randomly - the view that I was dragging disappears when I reset the positions. The listview is there, but the smaller view isn't there.

To help debug this. I print out the co-ordinates, visibility etc. of the top view controller once the mysterious disappearing occurs. The co-ords are exactly as they are supposed to be. Everything is working fine except on the screen, there is a big black void where it is supposed to be.

This problem scales out to when I get on the other side of the threshold and start transacting back and forth between the fragments this problem begins to happen as well. But I think its the same problem.

**Questions**

1. Is there a sure fire way to force-redraw / paint Views in android? I have tried a variety of these with no luck. Am I missing something?
2. Is this common? Am I missing something simple?

Any help would be great. Please let me know if you need any more info :)

~ Dan

Comment: where you able to figure this out ? Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397395/drag-and-drop-between-two-fragments   I am looking for logic to drag and drop the view from one fragment to another .