# drag and drop between two fragments?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-animation

I have a particular requirement where i need to drag a element in one screen then another fragment becomes visible where i can drop the dragged view .

what is the best way to achieve this ? I am not sure how to achieve this behavior between two fragments .Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

THE basics we need to understand is these constants for drag and drop both applicable for activity and fragments

> **DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED**
>
> **DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED**
>
> **DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED**
>
> **DragEvent.ACTION_DROP**
>
> **DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED**

now you need to make fragment VISIBLE ON DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED OR STARTED
above calls are properly explained following links

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Here iam leaving you with few good links....

https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/improved-drag-drop-for-gridview/