# Drag and drop between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop

I am working on drag and drop between two different fragments visible at same time on UI.

I want to drag view from one fragment into the other fragment. I am able to drag it between the fragment but what i am facing not good is that i can't listen onDrag on second fragment for the view of first fragment.

In Short the OnDragListener on second fragment should listen for the views dragged from first fragment.

I have searched alot on google and stackoverflow. Didn't find any answer.

[Drag and Drop view between two Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283904/drag-and-drop-view-between-two-fragments)

[drag and drop between two fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397395/drag-and-drop-between-two-fragments)

I somebody knows please share.

Comment: have you found a solution? Please post if you have

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating an overlaying View above both Fragments, which should not intercept touches, but as soon as you start dragging the view - a copy of it will be created in this overlay and follow the dragging? I can't see any other way of implementing this, since two Fragments have separate view hierarchies and the only way I can see is transfer the View through Activity's view hierarchy

BTW is there any way to avoid using of two Fragments? What kind of use case do you have?

Comment: I am working on tablet for an app which contains 5 different sections which needs to be appeared at same time. In order to keep the code clean i have used multiple fragments to handle them separately. Whats more the fragments are interacting with each other by passing data.

There should be a way something like creating interface but still i am not able to do it in proper way for this scenerio.

Comment: Then I would suggest to have a look at [GestureOverlayView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html) since it is a successor of FrameLayout - you should be able to add views there and it seems to have functionality for delegating touches to underlying views